# Indexing external URLs served by a different TYPO3 instance

Tags: typo3, tx-indexed-search

We have a setup in which a part of a TYPO3 website is served by a different TYPO3 instance. The main page is hosted at let's say `https://example.com`, whereas the the external page is hosted starting at `https://example.com/subdir` by a different TYPO3 instance. The following diagram hopefully helps to visualize this a bit.

```
Site root (https://example.com)
├─ Internal page (served by main instance)
│  ├─ Child page
│  └─ Another child page
├─ ...
├─ External page (https://example.com/subdir, served by external TYPO3 instance)
│  ├─ Child page (https://example.com/subdir/child-page)
│  └─ Another child page (https://example.com/subdir/another-child-page)
├─ ...
└─ Internal page (served by main instance)
```

This is done on the main instance with the help of a literal sub-directory, an `.htaccess` file therein and a few rewrite rules. Intuitively, I thought the external pages could be indexed with the help of the ["Indexing External websites" configuration](https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-indexed-search/main/en-us/IndexingConfigurations/IndexingExternals/Index.html). But this seemingly doesn't work.

**Can this be done or does the "external" URLs have to be served by the same instance as the internal URLs?**

Comment: Please explain what _doesn't work_ mean exactly. What exactly have you tried, how does your configuration look like? Do you have some kind of access protection or similar in place? Also check your logs for details.

Comment: Thanks, [@mathias-brodala](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6812729), for your reply. Are you saying, it **can** be done with indexed search? The problem I see is, that visiting (or automatically crawling) an external page, served by a different TYPO3 instance, will never be added to the index of the main instance, because they don't have shared database. So what would be the use case of "Indexing external URLs"?

Comment: Visiting the external website will indeed do nothing, you will need to trigger indexing from your local site. You can use the CLI commands of the crawler extension for this: https://docs.typo3.org/p/tomasnorre/crawler/main/en-us/ExecutingTheQueue/RunningViaCommandController/Index.html

Comment: Thanks, again, for your help! I guess my question was unclear and should rather be if there need to be links on the main site to targets on the external site in order for them to be indexed. If there are links, indexed_search will follow and index them. I was wondering, if that is necessary or if an external site can also be included in the search results, even without any links connecting the two.